# How to require a specific field gets passed a value when saving Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I’m trying to track which user last updated an object:

```
Class MyModel(models.Models):
    updater_id = models.ForeignKey(Users)
    …other fields…
```

However, I can’t figure out how to require that updater_id be included each time my object is saved.

First I tried overriding save:

```
    def save(self, updater_id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.updater_id = updater_id
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I realized however that this will break anything native to Django (i.e. MyModel.objects.create())

Next I tried grabbing it from kwargs:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.updater_id = kwargs[“update_fields”][“updater_id”]
        except:
            raise Error
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

updated_fields, however is only rarely used (i.e. default behavior for object.save() is to not use updated_fields)

Then I tried adding a flag:

```
Class MyModel(models.Models):
    updater_id = models.ForeignKey(Users)
    updater_updated_flag = models.BooleanField(default=True, editable=False)  # default=True so first create/save works

    def update_updater_id(self, user_id):
        self.updater_id = user_id
        self.updater_updated_flag = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.updater_updated_flag:
            self.updater_updated_flag = False
        else:
            raise Exception("Must call update_updater_id() before calling save on this object")

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I figured I would ensure the updater_id is updated before save can be called. I realized, however, that this will break create_or_update(), unless I want to wrap it in a try catch and, if the object exists, get the object and call update_updater_id, which already defeats the whole purpose.

Finally I tried django-model-util’s fieldtracker:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.tracker.has_changed(“updater_id”):
            raise Error
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Sometimes, however the value will not change (i.e. same user edited it again).

And now I’m out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [django-currentuser](https://github.com/PaesslerAG/django-currentuser). Not a universal solution, but it got the job done for me.